# Record audio in apple watch using bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, watchkit, apple-watch

I know how to record audio using watch speaker. But is there any api available to record using bluetooth headset? So that recording is possible without presenting the audio input controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such API available to record using Bluetooth headset. If a call is established from watch which has a headset paired does not route voice output to headset rather it uses its default speaker and mic as output and input